# Cannot access value from property in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a class

```
public class GlobalVariable
{
    private Guid _gebruikerID=Guid.Empty;

    public Guid GebruikerID
    {

        get
        {

            return _gebruikerID;

        }

        set
        {

            _gebruikerID = value;

        }

    }


}
```

now I create an instance of that class

```
GlobalVariable gv = new GlobalVariable();
```

now I assign a value to that instance

```
foreach (var item in Gebruiker)
  {

    lblGebruikerID.Text = "GebruikerID: " + Convert.ToString(item.GebruikerId);
    gv.GebruikerID = item.GebruikerId;

  }
```

now the last step is that I want to use gv.GebuikerID' value in another event

```
protected void btnShowIDs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblAdressIDToBeDeleted.Text = gv.GebruikerID.ToString();

    }
```

but unfortunately it shows me 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 but when I put breakpoint in the foreach loop it does show me the GUID.

Comment: I think you didn't post the `new` in that last step.

Comment: so; `gv` is a field on the form? is this the same form instance between the `foreach` loop and the `btnShowIDs_Click`? in particular, is this a web scenario? if it is web: that is a completely different instance between clicks. Presumably `item.GebruikerId;` do actually have sensible non-zero values?

Comment: You still have the same problem as in your prev question, called a  1-N relation. You have multiple users, one (1) GlobalVariable .

Comment: @MarcGravell yes it is web. What would be ideal solution? because I want to grab the value I got in foreach loop

Comment: This indeed asssigns a value: `gv.GebruikerID = item.GebruikerId;` But how do we know that `item.GebruikerId` is initialized at this point? Show the code where you fill `Gebruiker` with instances of whatever type it holds (`var` isn't helpful to understand your code).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - it is, by "when I put a breakpoint".

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have create that instance before all page_load

Comment: @user2983359 right; if it is web, the page class (the thing with `GlobalVariable gv = new GlobalVariable();`) is `new`-ed each time you do something, so `gv.GebruikerID` will be empty. Is this webforms? frankly, the answer there is : stop using webforms. Somehow you will need to convey the state you intend to display. You *could* use something like sessionstate or viewstate for that, but IMO both are just horrible - but every "good" solution here IMO starts with not having anything at all to do with webforms.

Comment: @user2983359: one thing is strange, you use a loop to initialize a single instance. Either you don't need a loop or you need more than one instance. If `Gebruiker` always contains a single object you should not use a collection.

Comment: @MarcGravell haha stop using webform. But I have no choice. I have to use it.

Comment: @user2983359 in a perfect world, I'd be looking at a "data-" html attribute and some client-side code to access it (nothing to do with C#). I don't see why you can't do that, but if you must use webforms, you're probably going to need to get very familiar with viewstate

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you very much. I'll see with viewState. Maybe that might help me.

Comment: @user2983359 btw, you're making your code *way* too complex: `public class GlobalVariable { public Guid GebruikerID {get;set;} }` - job done

Comment: @MarcGravell I can try this solution.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks I have tried with ViewState and it is working :).